# print first 2 non duplicate numbers javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I encountered this problem in a javascript test wherein I need to print first 2 non duplicate numbers and here is my partial attempt.

```
var list = [5, 23, 23, 5, 66, 3, 23, 7, 3, 0];


var locObj = {};
var count = 1;

for(var i =0; i< list.length; i++){
  if(!(list[i] in locObj))
  locObj[list[i]] = 1;
  else
    locObj[list[i]] = count++;
}

console.log(locObj);//has an object with value as 1 if its non duplicate and the number of occurrences in the case of duplicate values.
```

I can further loop through locObj and determine whose value is equal to 1 and then print 2 values. But since javascript keys are not ordered, I'm unable to print 66 and 7 which is the expected out. How to solve it? Appreciate any other better approach to solve the problem as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first map digits as key and repetition as value, then loop again on array and select first two digits which has value as 1 on mapping object

```js
var list = [5, 23, 23, 5, 66, 3, 23, 7, 3, 0];

let mapping = list.reduce((op,inp)=>{
  op[inp] = op[inp] || 0
  op[inp]++
  return op
},{})

let firstTwo = []

list.forEach(v=> {
  if(mapping[v] === 1 && firstTwo.length < 2){
    firstTwo.push(v)
  }
})

console.log(firstTwo);
```

Comment: This solution seems to be more easy to infer and understand.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use a Map instead, whose iteration methods (here, [`entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/entries)) iterate in insertion order. Count up into a Map, similar to what you're doing, then get the Map's entries, filter by those with a count of 1, and slice to get the first two:

```js
var list = [5, 23, 23, 5, 66, 3, 23, 7, 3, 0];
const countByNum = new Map();
list.forEach((num) => {
  countByNum.set(num, (countByNum.get(num) || 0) + 1);
});
const firstTwoNonDupes = [...countByNum.entries()]
  .filter(([, count]) => count === 1)
  .slice(0, 2)
  .map(([num]) => num);
console.log(firstTwoNonDupes);
```

Comment: Never would have thought of this solution during a constrained javascript test :)

Answer (score 1):

You could take a combination of a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), where the map stores just the seen values and a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) as result set for value who are seen ones.

```js
function getFirstTwoNonDuplicateValues(array) {
    var map = new Map,
        result = new Set,
        value;
    
    for (value of array) map.set(value, map.has(value)
        ? result.delete(value)
        : result.add(value));
    
    return [...result].slice(0, 2);
}

console.log(getFirstTwoNonDuplicateValues([5, 23, 23, 5, 66, 3, 23, 7, 3, 0]));
```

Comment: Interesting solution, i think it is more efficient due to a single loop and fewer operations compared to other solutions?